# Workflow for restarting a HTTP server from Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure, workflow, read-eval-print-loop

A Clojure-based project of mine uses the netty (required by [aleph](https://github.com/ztellman/aleph)) web server. I start the server, along with other components, in a `web.clj` file like this:

```
(ns myproject.web)

(def server (atom nil))

(defn initialize []
  (if @server
    (println "Warning: already initialized")
    (let [port 8001]
      (println (format "Starting http://localhost:%s/" port))
      (swap! server (fn [_] (start-http-server
                             (wrap-ring-handler app-routes)
                             {:port port}))))))

(defn shutdown []
  (when @server
    (do
      (println "Shutting down web server")
      (@server)
      (swap! server (fn [_] nil)))))

(defn reinitialize []
  "Run this on the REPL to reload web.clj and restart the web server"
  (myproject.web/shutdown)
  (use :reload-all 'myproject.web)
  (myproject.web/initialize))
```

The server instance is stored in a Clojure *atom*, so that it can be stopped later.

I use [Emacs and Swank](https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure#readme) to directly launch the server on the REPL like this (after compiling `web.clj` with `C-c C-k`):

```
user> (myproject.web/initialize)
```

Whenever `web.clj` or other dependent modules are edited, I must

1. remember NOT to recompile `web.clj` using C-c C-k because the atom holding the running instance would vanish (due to the atom from a newly compiled module) from the REPL.
2. Run `(myproject.web/reinitialize)` which stops the server *and then* reloads the module before starting it again.

There are two problems with this:

- Often I forget point #1 and press `C-c C-k` anyway. This causes the loss of server atom in REPL, leading to having to kill swank (or restart emacs) so that I can start the server at the same port number.
- `:reload-all` doesn't report compile errors as friendly as `C-c C-k` (ugly traceback vs concise clickable errors).

How can I best address these two problems in this edit-compile-restart workflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace

```
(def server (atom nil))
```

with

```
(defonce server (atom nil))
```

that way when you evaluate the buffer it will not redefine server.

Answer (score 2):

for your first problem you can store the atom in a different namespace and on load only overwrite it if it is not yet defined. putting it in it's own namepspace will prevent it from being erased by the reload-all